# visual studio 2015 bower intellisense Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bower

I downloaded visual studio 2015 and created asp.net vnext empty project.I added bower.json and grunt.js
When I define dependency, intellisense works fine for items but when I define item version intellisene not works and always says not available.

Comment: connection problems? works fine for me.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Was working yesterday and now, `Loading...` then `Unavailable` - Obviously I have connection cause I posted this.

Comment: Same for me, i believe this is a proxy issue. (For me at least) as I'm in a corporate environment.

Comment: Same problem ... I am able to get version for NPM packages in package.json with no problem. It seems to be limited to the dependencies section of the bower.json file. Is there some other way to find the versions for these files?

Comment: I did a quick test of this switching my laptop to my personal hotspot and restarting VS2015, but the "Unavailable" issue still persists. NPM's intellisense works fine so this certainly seems to be Bower specific.

I have no problem getting information about the package - it's only the version numbers that don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Only available since July 20th, 2015 on a Visual Studio update

more on it in [Scott Guthrie blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/released-today-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-4-6-asp-net-5-ef-7-previews)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest simply don't use VS 2015 just yet. It is good for some random checking and Hello World apps but i tried to convert my N-tier Enterprise application into V-Next MVC 6 using VS2015. It simple is not working for me.

VS keeps on restarting and it hangs when it goes to resolve dependencies automatically.